# Acquring bearer token from .NET Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-5.0

I have the following scenario: normal .NET Web API on 4.8 which works as Identity API, and a .NET 5.0 Web API that needs to have a bearer token to be identity API (4.8 .net one).

I'm struggling what configuration to be use in the .NET Core API.

```
// Normal .net API on 4.8 net work as Identity API configurations
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    PublicClientId = "self";

    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, null, null),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = 15
)),
            AllowInsecureHttp = false,
            RefreshTokenProvider = new ApplicationRefreshTokenProvider(),
        };

    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
}

// .NET 5.0 API that need to have bearer token to be identity API (.net 4.8 from above)
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer("oauth", o =>
        {
            o.Authority = "http://localhost:1000/Token";
            //o.Audience = "test";
        });
}
```

I think I'm going in the wrong direction with `.AddJwtBearer(...)` because tokens that are produced by Identity API are "normal" bearer token and not JWT.

I will really will appreciate any help in order to achieve the correct configurations in .NET Core API

Comment: The direction that you are following is correct , in the client side setting the authority and the audience it's enought, then it will check the validate of the token with your oauth server(authority) ,  can you tell me what problem you have or what error are you receiving ?, have you created the resources and clients in the oauth side ?

Comment: looks like you're using an external authentication provider with OAuth, so the app's configuration can use the `ApplicationBuilder.AddOAuth` extension method (not `AddJwtBearer`).

Comment: @KingKing i did not go with AddOAuth because i checked all properties which are provided there. From my prespective in case of using this method user need to be redirected to OAuth provider (the property called AuthorizationEndpoint) and when token is aquired to perfrom callback (CallbackPath). In my case i have to use grant type - password and silently to send user and password without end user to notify.

Comment: @CristianGerani I have created simple clients into oauth side but there i do not have definitions per client regarding Audiences, only ClientId and ClientSecret. But how this will work when client will expect JWT and eventually oauth provider will return reference(normal bearer) token

Comment: looks like you just have a separate ***sign-in*** service. So basically the authentication is still done inside your web, the signing-in however is done by calling a remote service. So the authentication scheme is of your choice which can be  cookies or bearer token. You design the sign-in service normally (as by Identity, it has a `PasswordSignInAsync` method).